# Why DisplayMemberPath is not getting displayed?

Tags: wpf, xaml

This is very basic, not sure why DisplayMemberPath is not showing, it just shows the class names.

```
    <ListView x:Name="lv" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=ShoppingList}" DisplayMemberPath="Name">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Item" Width="150"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

where `root` is the name of Window.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Product> ShoppingList { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {

        ShoppingList = new ObservableCollection<Product>();

        ShoppingList.Add(new Product() { Name = "Coffee", Price = 4, Info = "Out of stock" });
        ShoppingList.Add(new Product() { Name = "Donut", Price = 2, Info = "Buy one get one free" });
        ShoppingList.Add(new Product() { Name = "Sandiwich", Price = 7, Info = "Comes with free Coffee" });

        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Not sure what am I missing?

```
public class Product
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public String Info { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Remarks in the [`DisplayMemberPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath?view=netcore-3.1#remarks) documentation:

> This property is a simple way to define a default template that describes how to display the data objects.

This won't work in conjunction with a GridView, where you set the [`DisplayMemberBinding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.gridviewcolumn.displaymemberbinding?view=netcore-3.1#remarks) property for the template of each column:

> This property associates a type of data from a data source to a column so that the column displays a set of values of that type.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=ShoppingList}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Item" Width="150"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

---

Or you don't set the ListView's `View` property at all:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=ShoppingList}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
```

But then you would usually not use a ListView, but the simpler ListBox.

Comment: DisplayMemberBinding doesn’t use binding and I think it should work with any control that has ItemsSource. It works in conjunction with it. I am sure I read that somewhere.

Comment: No, as you have realized, it doesn't work with a GridView. And it would not make sense, because you have multiple columns. It would of course work without the GridView.

Comment: You have a point and it does work. Generally it is used without binding so I wasn't sure at first.